# How to get a file after uploading it to Azure Storage

Tags: windows, azure, azure-storage, file-storage, azure-files

I had uploaded files mostly media files to Azure's File Storage, which I am able to see in Azure's Explorer as well.  But when I view the file as anonymous user, I am not able to view the file.  Tried to check with Permissions setting as well, but to no avail.

Any help would be welcomed :)

Comment: What's the ACL on the container where you uploaded the files? For the blobs to be anonymously visible, it should be set to `Blob` or `Public`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure files have Shared Access Signatures (SAS). This is a key that you compute with the storage account key, that gives access to a particular URL. Here is an example (storage account name is obfuscated here):

```
https://mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net/sampleshare/2.png?sv=2015-04-05&sr=f&si=sampleread&sig=Zq%2BfflhhbAU4CkCuz9q%2BnUFEM%2Fsg2PbXe3L4MeCC9Bo%3D&sip=0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255
```

You have sample code on how to create a SAS with Azure files at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/, §"Generate a shared access signature for a file or file share".

You can also do it interactively with a number of tools. For instance, [CloudXPlorer](http://clumsyleaf.com/products/cloudxplorer) has this feature.

Comment: I am using, File Storage not blob storage. I don't seem to find those settings for file storage.

Comment: shared access signature shoul work for file. I'll update my answer. sorry for the error.

Comment: I changed the answer from Blob storage to Azure file share