# Not able to view uploaded Blob File

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I uploaded a file using node to Azure's Blob storage, I could find that being listed there in my azure account - But when I try to access that file, I get Blob not found error. Any help would be appreciated.

Find the screenshot.[image]

Comment: Check my comments and answer to your other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399532/how-to-get-a-file-after-uploading-it-to-azure-storage. The answer holds true for blobs as well.

Comment: bro, this is for blob storage! This ain't duplicate, I am getting different error as blob not found

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment, the reason is the same. Check your container ACL please. If it is `Private`, change it to `Blob` or `Container`. If you want to keep it `Private`, use Shared Access Signature as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Its already marked as blob

Comment: @GauravMantri Please find the attached screenshot as well

Comment: I see it now. **Please accept my apologies for marking it as duplicate** but in my defense I would not have done it if you had shared the screenshot earlier. Let me flag this question to be reopened again. From the screenshot, it looks like an issue with the portal. What happens when you  open the blob in some other tool? Will it be possible to share the URL of the blob?

Comment: This is the URL, I get when I try downloading the image https://tureetdev.blob.core.windows.net/5678f6e9e85753c833db7f88/1450768125999_Screenshot%20(6).png?sv=2015-04-05&ss=bqtf&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2015-12-22T15%3A41%3A21Z&sig=dFc2bIkozNhx5%2BVCxSfAYJH3KT9EuuYaOAzqNps28n4%3D

Comment: @GauravMantri does blob storage takes some time, before the url goes live?

Comment: I think I know what's happening. Please try this URL and see if this works - https://tureetdev.blob.core.windows.net/5678f6e9e85753c833db7f88/1450768125999_Screenshot%2520(6).png?sv=2015-04-05&ss=bqtf&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2015-12-22T15%3A41%3A21Z&sig=dFc2bIkozNhx5%2BVCxSfAYJH3KT9EuuYaOAzqNps28n4%3D.

Comment: Yeah! The URL You had shared is working.

Comment: What was the issue bro?

Comment: I believe it is an issue with Azure Portal. Essentially the name with which your blob is saved is `1450768125999_Screenshot%20(6).png`. However, the `%` sign is not escaped in the URL. All I did was escaped the `%` sign with `%25` and all worked well! So I changed the blob name in the URL to `1450768125999_Screenshot%2520(6).png` and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is an issue with either Azure Portal or the tool/library you used to create the URL.

Essentially the name with which your blob is saved is `1450768125999_Screenshot%20(6).png`. However, the `%` sign is not escaped in the URL.

All I did was escaped the `%` sign with `%25` and all worked well! So I changed the blob name in the URL to `1450768125999_Screenshot%2520(6).png` and it worked just fine.

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks!